# Как запустить функцию при наступлении события на одном из одинаковых селекторов Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function txt() {
        $('.put').fadeIn(2000);
}

$('.add_to_cart_button').click(function(e){
  txt();
})
```

```css
.put{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_to_cart_button">
  <div class="put">add</div>
</div>

<div class="add_to_cart_button">
  <div class="put">add</div>
</div>

<div class="add_to_cart_button">
  <div class="put">add</div>
</div>
```

Как запустить функцию txt() на элементе, на котором произошло событие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function txt(parent) {
  $(parent).find('.put').fadeIn(2000);
}

$('.add_to_cart_button').click(function(e){
  txt(this);
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь